# How to read xml from file inside public directory in react project in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch

Inside my react project public folder, I have a file named **mySurvey.xml**, I want to read that file inside my src directory, so for simplicity i tried reading it inside app.js

[image]

So inside my app.js I tried reading it with **fetch API**, but it returns the index.html text as response and not the content of the file.

```
 // Fetch Function   
   fetch("./mySurvey.xml")
   .then(response => response.text())
   .then(data=>{
     console.log('File Data = ',data)
     let parser = new DOMParser();
     let xml = parser.parseFromString(data, "application/xml"); 
     console.log('XML = ',xml);
   })
  .catch(error =>{
     console.log('My Error = ',error);
```

[image]
})

In the network tab, I checked fetch API is creating this url
**http://localhost:3000/mySurvey.xml**

**And this loads up the html page And doesn't give up xml data**

Please guide me is my approach correct or is there a better way!!

Note:- There are a lot of xml files inside public folder like mySurvey.xml and I will receive fileName based on which I have to read data from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fetch('abc.xml')
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then(xmlString => new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml"))
      .then(data => setItem(data))
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

Fetch cannot parse xml by default. So, I am using DOMParser to parse the string to an XML object. As soon as you get the xml object, you can store it in your state and manipulate it as you wish

Comment: Basically, my problem is I am unable to reach to mySurvey.xml in fetch request

Comment: @John That is weird. It should fetch from public folder without any problem. I just tried it out a new project on my machine and it worked

Comment: In which file did you write the fetch API code, can you share the screen shot please of that file and code

Comment: @John He wrote in App.js in src as far as I got to know

Comment: In the network tab, I checked fetch API is creating this url
http://localhost:3000/mySurvey.xml

And this loads up the html page And doesn't give up xml data

Comment: Thanks, it worked, issue was with my base path, set in .env file